# What to do when surrounded by more than one enemy in Free Fire?

Tags: free-fire

Sometimes I get surrounded by more than a single enemy. Also, they start to shoot at me together.

In the open field what's the best strategy to escape alive from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the introduction of better gloo walls, the best strategy is for you to use them effectively. Carefully note from which direction you are getting shot at(you can easily do that). If you are confident you can introduce counter fire and try to make the enemy run for cover. If not place the gloo walls strategically . If you have two or more use them so that the enemy does not know behind which wall you are. Once I had a guy killing a few others in peak, I decided to engage him. It was the start of the match so I only had taken a AK and I didn't know he had a SPAS12. He was near a house and I was behind a tree. What he did was: after taking few shots, he realised that he needs to get closer to attack me. So he placed a gloo wall few metres away and hid behind it and probably recovered some health. Then he again placed a gloo wall few metres from the first one and quickly ran to it. While making the run, I couldn't shoot him because I didn't know when he was going to make the run. Like the same he did once more time and by this time he had gained enough distance to hurt me with the shotgun. Since I had a AK, I was killed. So it is all about strategic placement. In case of multiple tangos try to lead one to another and kill the remaining one after their fight is over. If both have spotted you then you stand little chance in open space. So avoid open areas. Make sure there  no one is present and then venture out

Answer (score 0):

You just can't take them on like that. Firstly, use everything you have,  pick up any gun around you and start a counter-offensive. Aim for their heads (goes without saying).

**Deliver them serious damage**, you know the panic when someone suddenly gives you a damage of over 80. It should discourage them from engaging you.

Next, as @vigneshrawan pointed, use **Gloo walls** judiciously. They can make a great difference.

You might even like a **flashbang**, and run in a pre-designated direction because the screen is gonna go white once it goes off, buying you time to hide, simply prone or find cover.

**Use your character's special abilities** such as Kla for a headshot punch or Kelly's sprinting to run. Run towards the shooter in a zig-zag way. Avoid sprinting here. My friend a guy with MP-40 with bare hands as the guy could barely aim with him jumping around and breaking into a run and stopping suddenly.

If you lose serious HP, like 100 or something then, prone and use med-kit, even if you don't  use it right then, you are likely to die but if so your enemy, keep shooting.In the end, **it is better to weigh your chances** and see what fits the situation best.

If you can **find a vehicle**, get in it and run away. With a med-kit then, even better as even vehicles get easily damaged.

Lastly, if you have nothing, **improvise**, sprint around, confuse the enemies, frustrate them by jumping, suddenly starting and crouching; do whatever it takes to win and of course, have fun.

Hope this helps and we see each other in the battleground.

Answer (score -1):

get stronger armor and better artillery. Kill as many as you can, and escape. Find some sort of cover, anywhere you can.

Comment: You should explain more so that it becomes helpful enough.